# Freemarker-Macros: How to use a macro twice?

Tags: freemarker

I am currently working on some contracts and the my freemarker macros are working fine. But now I have to use the same macro twice and I'm getting the report: Expected a hash, but this evaluated to a number
It seems the same macro cant do the same thing twice, the macro I am currently using is:

```
[#macro TeilbetragProzent]
[#assign gesamt = ((verkaufsauftrag.beteiligungGesamt)!"") /]
[#assign nominale = ((nominale.betrag)!"")/]
[#if (gesamt?string)!=""] 
[#assign prozent = ((nominale/gesamt)*100)/]
${(prozent)?string["0.##"]}
[#else]100
[/#if]
[/#macro]
```

I tried to change it a little:

```
[#macro TeilbetragProzent2]
[#assign gesamt2 = ((verkaufsauftrag.beteiligungGesamt)!"") /]
[#assign nominale2 = ((nominale2.betrag2)!"")/]
[#if (gesamt2?string)!=""] 
[#assign prozent2 = ((nominale2/gesamt2)*100)/]
${(prozent2)?string["0.##"]}
[#else]100
[/#if]
[/#macro]
```

Still not working... Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than an issue in the macro, I believe your issue lies in the second assign directive: `[#assign nominale = ((nominale.betrag)!"")/]`. You are trying to assign the value of the node `betrag` in the hash variable `nominale` (likely number, based on the error message) to a variable of the same name, `nominale`. If you change the variable name to something, I think you will have success.

```
[#macro TeilbetragProzent]
[#assign gesamt = ((verkaufsauftrag.beteiligungGesamt)!"") /]
[#assign nom = ((nominale.betrag)!"")/]
[#if (gesamt?string)!=""] 
[#assign prozent = ((nom/gesamt)*100)/]
${(prozent)?string["0.##"]}
[#else]100
[/#if]
[/#macro]
```